# Swf file:What is the best way to develop swf file?

Tags: iphone, android, flash

I know we can generate swf file by creating action script project in flex sdk and also using cs5 we can create swf file. I want to create swf files for running in mobile devices like android,iphone. What is the best approach to create a swf file that runs in both android and iphone. I am very new to swf technology. please guide me.

thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash is not supported in iOS so there is no way of showing it on iPhone or iPad.

Take a look at [Google's Swiffy Project](http://swiffy.googlelabs.com/) it allows SWF to HTML5 conversion, allowing the content to be displayed on iPhone.